# Passing Blob to new Audio

Tags: javascript, blob

I'm trying to create an audio element using `new Audio()`. The data I get back from Dropbox contains an object w/ a `fileBlob` property

```
fileBlob: Blob(5498932)
  size: 5498932
  type: "application/octet-stream"
  __proto__: Blob
```

How can I get this into a format that can be passed to `new Audio()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`HTMLAudioElement`-Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement), expects a `URLString`.

For that, you can use [`createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)

```
new Audio(URL.createObjectURL(fileBlob))
```

Answer (score 1):

`const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(downloadPath.fileBlob);`

Seems to work